# AirPrint shows two back (< <) icons

Tags: ios, xcode, back-button, navigationbar, airprint

i am willing to export some pdf files from my application using AirPrint in iOS. however when i present the **UIPrintInteractionController** it shows two back icons as < <. I have attached the images and code to get what i am doing. I think the icons are one for my own navigation bar and another of **UIPrintInteractionController**, i tried to hide the barItems but didn't work out. here's the code:

```
UIPrintInteractionController *printController = [UIPrintInteractionController sharedPrintController];
            printController.delegate = self;

            NSMutableArray *printingItems = [NSMutableArray array];
            if(exportCSV) [printingItems addObject:csvData];
            if(exportPDF) [printingItems addObject:pdfData];

            UIPrintInfo *printInfo = [UIPrintInfo printInfo];
            printInfo.outputType = UIPrintInfoOutputGeneral;
            printInfo.jobName = @"MyHealth Export";
            printInfo.duplex = UIPrintInfoDuplexLongEdge;
            printController.printInfo = printInfo;
            printController.showsPageRange = YES;
            printController.printingItems = printingItems;

            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                [printController presentAnimated:YES completionHandler:^(UIPrintInteractionController *printInteractionController, BOOL completed, NSError *error) { //code}
```

Image:
[image]

Any help is appreciated.. Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure its two buttons and not one? It looks like you or something else may have set the title of the controller underneath or its Back button label to @"<". Normally it would show the larger < symbol followed by either the title of the controller below or "Back" if the title was too large. Somehow that seems to be set to "<" from what I can see.

Is there anywhere where you change the title of the navigationItem? Perhaps in the attribute inspector for the navigation item which lets you put in a Back button label?

Comment: hey thanks a lot brother, i seriously dint thought it that way, you were right they were not two buttons instead the second one was been set as the tile to back button (don't know how!!). I added the following code to remove the title:

`self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"" style:self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem.style target:nil action:nil];`